# How to nicely rotate a DT datatable so scrolling is vertical

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have a DT renrered in my shiny app and it has a lot of columns.

```
 mtcars2 <- cbind(mtcars, mtcars)
 mtcars2 <- cbind(mtcars, mtcars2)
```

[image]

I would like the table to be inverted as in the column names will be the first column and then all records vertical so I don't need to scroll horizontally but vertically.

[image]

I still want mpg to be a column, cyl to be a column etc. Just the way the table is displayed is inverted.

It that anyhow feasible in DT?

Thank you

Comment: can you show expected output and code you have tried?

Comment: See above added a screenshot of what I want to see. Of course the text has to show correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can rotate with the CSS property `transform`:

```
  div(
    style = "transform: rotateZ(-90deg); transform-origin: bottom;",
    DTOutput("yourOutputId")
  )
```

Comment: have you seen what it yields as result??

Comment: @Arkadiw Yes. I tested with a simple app, containg only a `DTOutput`, and the result was fine. What is the problem you encounter?

Answer (score -1):

t is for transpose. Use the t(...) function from base R.

```
mtcars2 <- cbind(mtcars, mtcars)
mtcars2 <- cbind(mtcars, mtcars2)

mtcars_t <- t(mtcars2)
```

Comment: I need my columns to remain as columns and my data.frame unchanged.